# Simple client node error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there, I have created rospackage "add" and client.cpp file.
when I compile the cpp file header file "add/AddTwoInts.h"
gives this error.No such file or directory,,,
Do you have any idea for this error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32967/simple-client-node-error/) by [Newbee](https://answers.ros.org/users/2241/newbee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-04-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2012-04-30**:
Your makefile can't locate the AddTwoInts.h file. It's either not in your path or the make file's not quite right

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-04-30**:
Please copy and paste the error from the console, and relevant snippets of what files generated the problem. http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're following the tutorials, I'm fairly certain that your `client.cpp` file is trying to subscribe to a topic of type `AddTwoInts` from the tutorials. If this is the case, it means that your package cannot find the necessary message description. In order to access this information, you must either re-define the message type in your package as per the tutorials, or add the beginner_tutorials package as a dependency in your package. Do this by adding the following to your manifest.xml:

```
<depend package="beginner_tutorials" />
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might forgot to uncomment rosbuild_gensrv() in CMakeLists.txt so you don't have the generated service message type.

---

Originally posted by [Bence Magyar](https://answers.ros.org/users/1102/bence-magyar/) with karma: 358 on 2012-04-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2